# Execute Task and wait for return whitout blocking the GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading

To make it as simple as possible for the example, im running a program which calls from the main thread a function which will return a status:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(check().ToString());
}

private bool check()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return true;
}
```

It will work as i want it to, it waits for the functions to finish and shows the return value, but doing it this way the GUI will be locked and cant be moved. Running it from another thread wont block the GUI, but i have to wait for the result so if i wait for the thread to finish im back to the same problem, the gui is locked.

Whats the best way to wait for the function to return its value without blocking the GUI?

Comment: BackgroundWorker, Task.Run, ThreadPool, …

Comment: You already answered yourself. Use Task. Just googling this will return a *lot* of results. `await Task.Run(()=>SomeHeavyMethod());` is all it's needed to run something in the background and return to the UI thread.`var result=await Task.Run(()=>SomeHeavyMethod());` will store the result, so you can use `MessageBox.Show` to display it afterwards

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i saw some post but didnt realizied its that easy to do it with async tasks, works perfectly fine thanks! Was completly stuck to solve it over the "regular" spawn a new thread way...